# How do I lock the height of a table row when I am using CSS to add a border to a cell in that row?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some jQuery script that is selecting a cell when I click it and I would like th row not to change height.

I have set the height of the table row with CSS but when I change the border on one single cell the whole row changes in height....

I tried to use the Table-Layout Css property but this didnt help. Any ideas what I can do?

```
    .EditTable td
    {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        border-right: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
        height: 26px;
        cursor:default;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    .EditTable td input
    {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        cursor:default;
        text-align: right;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        outline-offset: 0;
    }

<table class="EditTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

      <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="">0</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="">0 akudsfsa fdhsad fiasgdf swae</div>
            </td>
            <td id="tempid1" class="highlightableTDCell">
                <div class="tempDiv">
                    <input id="Text2" value="0.00"/>
                </div>
            </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="">0</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="">0 akudsfsa fdhsad fiasgdf swae</div>
            </td>
            <td id="Td1" class="highlightableTDCell">
                <div class="tempDiv">
                    <input id="Text1" value="0.00"/>
                </div>
            </td>
      </tr>

</table>



//highlighting cell
gridview.prototype.borderiseTDCell = function (obj) {
    //jQuery('#' + obj.id + ' div input').blur();

    jQuery(obj).find('div input').blur();
    this.unBorderiseTDCells();
    var jQueryTableCell = jQuery('#' + obj.id);
    jQueryTableCell.css('border', '2px solid #000000');

};

gridview.prototype.unBorderiseTDCells = function () {

    var cellToUnHighLight = jQuery('.highlightableTDCell');
    cellToUnHighLight.css('border-width', '0px 1px 1px 0px');
    cellToUnHighLight.css('border-color', '#C1C1C1');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how the [W3C box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) works. When you use CSS `height`, you are setting the height of the element's contents, not including padding and borders.

Since you're adding a border to the cell via jQuery, you should recalculate the height to compensate the borders' extra pixels.